# Will the Camdiox brand 165mm fit with the SFH-14 filter holder for the Samyang 14mm lens?

Tags: lens, filters

[this is an example of one of the filters](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/251884181674?ViewItem=&item=251884181674) - Camdiox 165x208x2.5

[this is the filter holder](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Samyang-SFH-14-Filter-Holder-for-Samyang-14mm-F2-8-ED-AS-IF-UMC/263717930888?epid=1637779546&hash=item3d66d04788:g:9NkAAOSw1ZBUwRRH) - SFH-14 filter holder designed specifically for the Samyang 14mm lens.

I was put off this specific filter holder for my Samyang 14mm after discovering there are only 3 available filters for it from Cokin; but I've heard these Camdiox filters are also compatible? They seem to have a bit more of a variety too, it seems.